# RPS Game App Not Working

Tags: javascript, html

I am working on an RPS game, and I am having a bit of trouble with getting it to work on a basic level before I style it. Here is my HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="rpsfinal1.css">
        <title>Shattered Template</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="corners">
            <h1 class="title">Rock Paper Scissors!</h1>
            <p>Welcome to a Rock Paper Scissors web app!1
            </p>
            <script type="text/javascript" src="rps.js"></script>
            <a href='linkhref.html' id='mylink'>Play Again</a>
            <input type="button" value="Rock" onClick="rockChoice()">
            <input type="button" value="Paper" onclick="paperChoice()">
            <input type="button" value="Scissors" onClick="scissorsChoice()">
            <p id="output"></p>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

And here is my JS:

```
var compare = function(choice1,choice2) {
if (choice1 === "rock") {
    if (choice2 === "rock") {
        console.log("It is a tie! The computer chose rock!");
        alert ("It is a tie!");
    }
    else if (choice2 === "paper") {
        console.log ("Sorry, you loose. :(");
        alert ("Sorry, you lose. :( The computer chose paper!");
    }
    else {
        console.log ("You win!");
        alert ("You win! The computer chose scissors!");
    }
}
else if (choice1 === "paper") {
    if (choice2 === "rock") {
        console.log ("You win!");
        alert ("You win! The computer chose rock!");
    }
    else if (choice2 === "paper") {
        console.log ("It is a tie!");
        alert ("It is a tie! The computer chose paper!");
    }
    else {
        console.log("Sorry, you lose. :(");
        alert ("Sorry, you lose. :( The computer chose scissors!");
    }
}
else {
    if (choice2 === "rock") {
        console.log ("You win!");
        alert ("You win! The computer chose rock!");
    }
    else if (choice2 === "paper") {
        console.log ("Sorry, you lose. :(");
        alert ("Sorry, you lose. :( The computer chose paper!");
    }
    else {
        console.log ("It is a tie!");
        alert ("It is a tie! The computer chose scissors!");
    }
        }
            };
    var rockChoice = function() {
var userChoice = "rock";

var computerChoice = Math.random();
console.log(computerChoice);
if (computerChoice >= 0 && computerChoice <= 0.33) {
    computerChoice = "rock";
    console.log(computerChoice);
}
else if (computerChoice >= 0.34 && computerChoice <= 0.66) {
    computerChoice = "paper";
    console.log(computerChoice);
}
else {
    computerChoice = "scissors";
    console.log(computerChoice);
}

compare(userChoice,computerChoice);
    }
    var paperChoice = function() {
var userChoice = "paper";

var computerChoice = Math.random();
console.log(computerChoice);
if (computerChoice >= 0 && computerChoice <= 0.33) {
    computerChoice = "rock";
    console.log(computerChoice);
}
else if (computerChoice >= 0.34 && computerChoice <= 0.66) {
    computerChoice = "paper";
    console.log(computerChoice);
}
else {
    computerChoice = "scissors";
    console.log(computerChoice);
}

compare(userChoice,computerChoice); 
    }
    var scissorsChoice = function() {
var userChoice = "scissors";

var computerChoice = Math.random();
console.log(computerChoice);
if (computerChoice >= 0 && computerChoice <= 0.33) {
    computerChoice = "rock";
    console.log(computerChoice);
}
else if (computerChoice >= 0.34 && computerChoice <= 0.66) {
    computerChoice = "paper";
    console.log(computerChoice);
}
else {
    computerChoice = "scissors";
    console.log(computerChoice);
}

compare(userChoice,computerChoice);
    }
```

I think that the reason the code is not working is that I may not be calling the functions correctly. Please let me know.
Thanks!

Comment: What specific errors are you getting in the console, or how is it not working?

Comment: You could make this much more efficient by putting the computer guessing code into a function by itself. Also note that there's absolutely no reason to use `var foo = function` as you can just use `function foo`.

Comment: That is the thing, I am not getting any errors, I am not getting anything back at all. It is weird...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I know its a little late but for those who are looking for the same thing:
- You are probably getting a "syntax error" because of the fact that you have an extra end bracket ( } ) at the end of the script on JS file.